# Can SYS_GUID() function generate same guid at another db

Tags: oracle, function, primary-key, guid

I am planning to use SYS_GUID() function to generate primary key in an existing table(Primary key does not exist in that table as of now)

I wanted to know if in certain case if we sync data from one database to another , is it possible that Oracle generate same guid at another db ?

Thank you

Comment: The reason anyone uses a `GUID` is because it is *globally unique*. It's right there in the name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. GUID is Globally unique. See alsi the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions153.htm

Answer (score 2):

To be correct, a collision might be possible but is very unlikely as SYS_GUID() involves stuff like host identifier and so on. If you are talking about the same database but different user/schemas you are perfectly safe as the unique number is unique across all users.

Comment: These are two different databases , sync needs to be done from one db to another (through Oracle's Golden Gate). In that case , would it be unique?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience regarding Oracle's Golden Gate. If you are using this I would suggest to contact support about that.